# Разработка оконных приложений на PHP

Tags: devel-studio, php

В чём минусы создания какой-то программы, например какого-нибудь агента для сайта созданной на php (Удобнее всего создавать на DevelStudio)?  Какие отличия от СИ++? Разумеется, в пхп меньше возможностей.
В общем, укажите, пожалуйста, отрицательные черты оконной программы на PHP?

Comment: PHP по сравнению C++ - один сплошной минус. Дурная у вас идея с PHP( извините за грубость )....

Comment: Ну а Вы поясните свою точку зрения. Я вот в этом не особо разбираюсь, с оконными приложениями только предстоит познакомится, для меня что на php, что на cи++. Главное, чтобы работала. Разумеется простенькие программки типа админки или агента и тп, мне проще написать на php, ибо его я знаю, а си нет. Мне охото узнать почему так все ненавидят PHP.

Comment: Почему ж так сразу - "ненавидят PHP"? Всему свое место. Для обработки золотого кольца, всё же лучше подойдёт специальный ювелирный ригель, нежели рашпиль. Хотя по сути, они выполняют одну и туже аботу.

Comment: [Ну как никогда к месту](http://www.gamer.ru/system/attached_images/images/000/411/621/original/1320276.jpg?1313841218)

Comment: @mctrane, PHP хоть и очень популярный серверный язык программирования, но тем не менее, в нем ооочень коряво реализованы многие вещи...ООП, к примеру.

Comment: да PHP- медленное и не логичное УГ, о чем вообще речь? =)

Comment: Как обычно одни догмы без каких бы то ни было аргументов.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Попробую аккуратно выразить общее мнение)

Если к программке нет особых требований, она не занимается сортировкой мегабайтов записей, созданием видеоэффектов, а используется только как клиент к сайту - делайте и не парьтесь. Она будет весить в сотни раз больше такой же программки на си и работать во столько же раз медленнее, но на малых нагрузках это роли не сыграет (для юзера нет особой разницы между 1.5мб и 300к и между 0.002 сек и 0.1 сек).

Главное, не забывайте об этих условиях - делать что-то осмысленное десктопное на php - страшный грех, ибо такой монстр будет весить метров 40 вместо 0.8 и выполнять простую операцию за 15 сек вместо 0.03.

Вообще говоря, "почти алгоритмический" php именно для мелких утилиток на каждый день весьма удобен. Не в продакшн, естественно)

Comment: ЗЫ: место на харде - это еще не самый ад, php течет как... хм...

Comment: Ясно, спасибо за хороший ответ!